# RPM Build error: Too many levels of recursion in macro expansion. It is likely caused by recursive macro declaration

Tags: centos7, rpm, packaging, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have been trying to build a rpm using rpmbuild but I keep getting the following error-

error: Too many levels of recursion in macro expansion. It is likely caused by recursive macro declaration.

**Environment Details-**
       rpmbuild --version
    RPM version 4.11.3

**part of .spec file-**

```
############# we define product here ###################
%define name abc

%define installdir /direc

############### product Info ###################
Summary: ABC management package
Name: %{name}
Version: %{version}
Release: %{release}
Source: %{name}-%{version}.tgz
Vendor: XYZ
License: Commercial
Group: System Environment/Libraries
Prefix: %{_prefix}
Buildroot: %{_tmpbuildroot}
################Dependencies ###########################
Requires : %{name} = %{version}, mod_php, php-pgsql
```

.rpmmacros file

```
    %_topdir               /home/jan/rpmbuild/
    %_tmppath              /home/jan/rpmbuild/tmp
    %_tmpbuildroot          /home/jan/rpmbuild/build
    %_buildroot         /home/jan/rpmbuild/BUILD
    %version                100.0.111.20200213
    %release                R_jenkins-XXXXXX-61
   %extra_require ameyocrm = 100.0.111.20200213
```

Command used to build rpm - 
**`sudo rpmbuild -bb -vv /home/jan/Work/BuildMachine/RPM/rpm_spec/rpm/SPECS/myspecfile.spec --target "\x86_64-redhat-linux\"`**

Answer (score 4):

`%name`, `%version` and `%release` macros are in-built. You should not try to override them. The `%name` macro is defined as the content of the `Name:` tag, same goes for `%version` and `%release`.

Rewrite it to something like this:

```
Name: abc
Version: 100.0.111.20200213
Release: R_jenkins-XXXXXX-61
Source: %{name}-%{version}.tgz
...
```

EDIT: As noted by @Danila:

```
Requires : %{name} = %{version}
```

Means that your package requires itself, which makes no sense.

#### EDIT2

If you want to be able to define the version number and release from outside, you can just define another macro:

```
%{!?_version: %define _version 100.0.111.20200213 }
%{!?_release: %define _release R_jenkins-XXXXXX-61 }

Name:       abc
Version:    %{_version}
Release:    %{_release}
```

these macros `_version` and `_release` are not standard and can be defined from outside your spec file.

Comment: Another is, `Requires : %{name} = %{version}` seems like a self-requirement, and should be eliminated.

Comment: Thanks Chris and Danila for your support. I tried again by removing the following line as recommended by you - 
`%{name} = %{version}`
But got the same error of recursive macro declaration. Also I cannot remove the following line- 
`Version: %{version}`
because the value of version is variable and will change with every build. So hard-coding the version is not an option for me. Can you suggest any other reason why I am getting this error of recursive macro declaration?

Comment: @nayasa I elaborated my answer a little more.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `--define name <name> --define release <number>` to the rpmbuild command.